# Какая модель машинного обучение тут подойдёт?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, статистика

Ребята может кто то из вас подкинет идеи

Есть задачка, нужно подобрать параметр - число остатков товарной позиции для интернет магазина. (он показывается для каждой карточки при добавлении в корзину)

чем больше остатков прописываем тем больше будет отмен
чем меньше остатков есть, меньше заработаем где не могли были быть отмены

почему возникают отмены?
ответ: при онлайн оформлении заказа проходит время с момента заказа до момента начала сборки и с момента начала сборки остатки могут уменьшиться (из оффлайн покупки), поэтому был введен дополнительный параметр как прогноз спроса.

Вопрос: какие варианты есть решения задачи для подбора самого оптимального остатка? (есть и другие признаки, решение задачи можно экстраполировать в сторону ритейла)

Comment: Начните стандартно с линейной регрессии. Только определитесь сначала: какие у вас есть признаки, какова целевая переменная, и какую метрику вы оптимизируете.

Answer (score 0):

Начните с того, что представье ваши данные в виде таблицы. Каждая строка -  это конкретный случай - если я понял правильно -  "добавления чего-то там в корзину",  по вертикали независимые параметры (количество остатков, время с момента заказа,.... даже не могу придумать, какие еще, но вам виднее) и независимая переменная (тут вообще загадка, что именно вы желаете оптимизировать).

Только потом можно будет думать про модель. Но на самом деле, вас же не модель как таковая интересует, вас интересует последующая оптимизация этой модели. Поэтому вполне может оказаться, что никакой "модели машинного обучения" тут и не понадобиться и все сведется к построению элементарной эконометрической модели и ее оптимизации (линейное программирование, динамическое программирование  и пр. в зависимости, что за модель получиться).

А что касается модели машинного обучения. Может оказаться так, что лучшей оказаться модель - ну допустим -  дерева решений, или еще веселее -  случайного леса. И что оно вам даст, что вы потом оптимизировать-то будете?

В общем, без структурированной информации о ваших исходных данных дальше говорить не о чем. Ведь вы даже не формализовали, что вы оптимизировать желаете.